# Why we can't share text or other files in Chat when we are permit to share image files

Tags: support, chat

I was trying to upload a text file in one of the chat rooms at [chat.stackoverflow.com](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/) & then I was showed an error warning as usual. So, I noticed that we are just allowed to upload & share image files in chat rooms.

Can I know why we are just allowed to share images and not text and other files. As we are always asked to share codes and other materials from other sites like paste.org, pastebin.org etc. SO has not provided any feature like that till date.

Comment: Are you `aware` that back `ticks` are for marking inline code?

Comment: Yes. I am aware of it. Sorry for wrong format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never felt the need to share a text file (or other non-image file) in chat, and I can't think of a good reason to do so.

Sharing code is certainly **not** a good reason - if your code is too big for pasting as is, it's too big for a chat conversation, and generally, for a Stack Overflow question.

Comment: Ok, but it really helps to add doubts and errors in chat by just put in a file and not the whole error logs, code etc.

Comment: @Harpreet but why would you need to add a text file for that? Just copy+paste your data into chat directly

Comment: Chat owner won't welcome these stuffs to be added in chats

Comment: @Harpreet that isn't true. If a conversation needs code, paste it (as long as it's a small amount, of course).

Comment: Thanks for the confidence. I also want to add something that sometimes  newbie developers like me do ask some silly questions as we are not having any physical tech-support with us. So it happens that Chat owners even revoke chat-room access from these users. So we are always careful for this type of stuff. :P

Comment: @Harpreet If new user barge into chat, post code and just keep asking "please fix" or "send me the solution" then yeah, he will be kicked out. But when the code is posted as part of the ongoing discussion and explained properly then it's totally valid.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: Yah, I appreciate it. But they are thrown out from room for the rest of their life too. :P